# Does the feat Double Strike work with the feat Vital Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Can the feats [Double Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/ascension-games-llc/combat-feats/double-strike-combat/) and [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/) be used simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Double Strike takes its own special standard action. Vital Strike only applies when you use the particular standard action known as Attack. You cannot use two standard actions simultaneously.